# Rollout VNC to all XP desktops via Group Policy?

Tags: group-policy, vnc

I would like to roll out a VNC solution that will allow me to connect to all the client computers on my windows networks.

Any recommendations appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.waynezim.com/2009/05/how-to-deploy-vnc-using-group-policy/

That should help, having read a bit it looks to cover all the bases.